# SQL Consolidating groups of data

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I have the following data in a table

```
col1      col2              col3
276328  | 999999999999  |   664116
927356  | 999999999999  |   664140
927356  | 999999999999  |   664140
927356  | 999999999999  |   664159
927379  | 999999999999  |   664172
```

code:

```
create table #table (col1 bigint, col2 bigint, col3 bigint)
insert into #table values(276328, 999999999999, 664116)
insert into #table values(927356, 999999999999, 664140)
insert into #table values(927356, 999999999999, 664140)
insert into #table values(927356, 999999999999, 664159)
insert into #table values(927379, 999999999999, 664172)
```

I need to update Col2 to the value in Col3 while grouping col1 and selecting the Min (col1) to apply to that sub group.

276328  and 927379 are on their own group but 927356 is a group that needs to have the lowest col3 number assigned to col2

So, the table above having been updated should look like this:

```
col1        | col2      | col3
276328      | 664116    | 664116
927356      | 664140    | 664140
927356      | 664140    | 664140
927356      | 664140    | 664159
927379      | 664172    | 664172
```

I have 2m+ rows to update so it has to be a bulk update not a loop.

How would I write the SQL to update the table?

Answer (score 3):

```
declare @myTable table (col1 bigint, col2 bigint, col3 bigint)
insert @myTable
select 276328  , 999999999999  ,   664116
union select 927356  , 999999999999  ,   664140
union select 927356  , 999999999999  ,   664140
union select 927356  , 999999999999  ,   664159
union select 927379  , 999999999999  ,   664172

update a
set a.col2 = b.col3
from @myTable a
inner join 
(
    select col1, MIN(col3) col3
    from @myTable 
    group by col1
) b
on a.col1 = b.col1


select * from @myTable
```

Comment: yup - this checks out Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
update t
set col2 = g.mincol3
from tbl t
join (
        select col1, min(col3) mincol3
        from tbl
        group by col1
    ) g on t.col1 = g.col1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `MySQL`

```
UPDATE table1 a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT col1, minCol
            FROM
            (
                SELECT col1, MIN(col3) minCol
                FROM tableName
                GROUP BY col1
            ) c
        ) b ON a.col1 = b.col1
SET a.col2 = b.minCol
```

Answer (score 0):

IF your RDBMS SQLServer2005+

```
UPDATE x
SET x.col2 = x.col3
FROM (SELECT col2, MIN(col3) OVER (PARTITION BY col1) AS col3
      FROm #table) x
```