# Merge and concat data at the same time

Tags: mysql, concatenation

What I am trying to do is the following: I have a database with 3 cols that together form a unique combination. This combination I extracted to a new table (table 1). Now I would like to match the data that is present in seperate columns to the unique 3 col combination. For example:

```
cat dog day twenty two
cat dog day twenty eleven
cat dog morning eleven ten
```

should become

```
cat dog day "twenty=two&twenty=eleven"
cat dog morning "eleven=ten"
```

As an extra comment I should add that I am unable to predict how many items should be concatenated.

I tried the following: The string field should be updated with a concat of all results of the unique combination of val3,val4 and val5.

```
UPDATE `db`.`table1` , `db`.`table2`
SET
string = 
(
SELECT group_concat(value1,'=',value2,'&') from table2
group by (val3,val4,val5)
)
WHERE 
(
`table1`.`val3`=`table2`.`val3` AND
`table1`.`val4=table2`.`val4` AND
`table1`.`val5=table2`.`val5`)
;
```

A hint or tip would be much appreciated. Thansks in advance.
For reference : [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699703/loop-through-all-rows-and-concat-unique-values-in-sql-table) does not work for me since I'm working with mySQL and I need to match 2 col's together.

Comment: I think we need to know more about your table sructure, but I think for starters you group concat should look probably a bit more like this :`GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(value1,'=',value2) SEPARATOR "&")` , try adding that and removing your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059740/sql-consolidating-groups-of-data/ for help with consolidating rows.

Comment: can we see sample records?

Answer (score 0):

Given this data structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `dummy` (
  `col1` varchar(20),
  `col2` varchar(20),
  `key` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

The following query will give you what you are asking for:

```
select col1, col2, group_concat(concat(`key`,'=', `val`) SEPARATOR '&') from dummy group by col1, col2
```